# How to organise my files using CMake?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, xcode4, cmake

I am having a bit of a problem with CMake regarding the organisation of my code within a solution.
I have for an habit to organise my namespace by creating a directory for each.
For example if I create something like this :

```
namespace test { namespace blabla  { ... } }
```

I would create a directory test and inside of it a directory blabla, however CMake does not make them appear in my Visual studio or Xcode project.

Is there a trick to get it done ?

Comment: what do you want to appear in your project? the files? the folders?

Comment: The folders and the files within them.

Comment: and (how) did you try to add them?

Comment: When I use the add_executable() command I give it my source files. Is there another way to do it ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try using the [source_group](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/source_group.html) command. After the call to `add_executable` add `source_group` statements to structure your project as you wish, e.g.:

```
source_group("test\\blabla" FILES file1.cpp file2.cpp)
```

Comment: It seems to do the trick ! Thank you. However I just get the folder "blabla" and not a folder "test" with blabla on it. Any idea ?

Comment: Nested source groups (using backslashes) work for me with CMake 2.8.5 and Visual Studio 2008 Pro.

Comment: I didn't test yet on vs but Xcode. I'll keep you posted. Thanks again !

Comment: It works great with visual studio but not xcode for some reason. The more I use xcode for C++, the more I think I should move to eclipse, even the link_directories that I set up works fine with VS but not Xcode.

Answer (score 5):

For grouping projects in VS you could use this way in CMake (ver after 2.8.3)

```
//turn on using solution folders
set_property( GLOBAL PROPERTY USE_FOLDERS ON)

//add test projects under 1 folder 'Test-projects'
FOREACH(TEST ${TESTS_LIST})
    add_test(NAME ${TEST}  COMMAND $<TARGET_FILE:${TEST}>)
    set_tests_properties( ${TEST} PROPERTIES TIMEOUT 1) 
    set_property(TARGET ${TEST} PROPERTY FOLDER "Test-projects")
ENDFOREACH(TEST)
```

Comment: Small side-note: Visual Studio Express does not support folders that's why USE_FOLDERS has to be set in the first place

Answer (score 2):

For Visual Studio: Make sure that all file names are unique. The result of compiling `dir/file.cpp` will be `obj/file.obj`. When the compiler compiles `otherdir/file.cpp` the result will be `obj/file.obj` - the previous object file **will be overwritten**. This is the case in VS 2008 and earlier versions, and I suspect it's still the case in VS 2010.

I too organise source code the way you do. I ended up using the following naming scheme: if the path to the source file would be `Dir/Subdir/AnotherSubDir/File.cpp`, then I'd name the file `Dir/Subdir/AnotherSubdir/DirSubdirAnotherSubdirFile.cpp`. Ugly? Yes. But it beats a project that won't link, and it's easy to figure out what the file name should be. I guess you could just append a sequence number on the file, but I thought it would be uglier. Also, if you forget to make the file name unique, the error isn't all that obvious to spot. Especially when you're tired, and your fiance/wife is waiting...

Comment: I get what you are saying but I didn't this problem but I'll keep it in mind since it will most likely happens. Thanks

Comment: Sorry for being a bit off topic, but I figured I should give you a heads up. Cheers!

Answer (score -2):

The accepted solution does not work for Xcode as of Xcode 6. However, there is a simple workaround:

1. Delete the references to source files from your Xcode project
   (delete them in the sidebar, then pick "Remove Reference").
2. Add the root folder(s) back, make sure "Create Group" is checked, and select
   the desired target(s).

Tada! Now your files should match the folder structure in Finder.